# iOS, textView half editable

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitextview

I need help in string formatting in iOS UITextView. I have a textView, for now it`s editable. Now I want to add a few strings. they should be like header and user must be able to type only under it, and when he press ENTER or DELETE line sting should change their position, so at the end it should look like

## Header 1(with color not editable)

/* user can type here

*/

## Header 2 (with color not editable)

/* user can type here

*/

I think i need to use delegate and attributed string or something,
but I can`t figure it out. HELP please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to make two labels and two text views on top of a scroll view. like

[image]

The heights of two text views can by dynamic depending on the text length. And in this case you can avoid endless IF conditions as you would need to put everything in a single Text view.

The advantage of this approach is the label text format will be very easy to set, you can simply set the attributed string in the storyboard.

Comment: actually here I have xib file
and i want text view to display whole text at once, and as I recall I can't change text view height by textView.frame.size.height += lineHeight right?

Comment: You can configure attributed string in Xib as well.

Comment: You just need to set some auto layout to change the height dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for help
Can you give me a tip about auto layout?

Comment: 1. uncheck Scrolling Enabled in .xib. 
2. [TextView setScrollEnabled:NO];   3. CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [TextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(TextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];

4. TextViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height;

Comment: With this 4 steps you can make your text view height dynamically change dependent on its text.